# Include external JavaScript library in an Angular 2 TypeScript Project

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, typescript, visual-studio-code

I've created new Angular 2 Project. And want to include parse.com sdk.
Added Parse.com as npm module

```
npm install parse --save
```

and installed typings for parse.com sdk

```
tsd install parse
```

Now i need to make the Parse Object available inside TypeScript Project.
No idea how to let system include it with typings, so that i can access the Typed Parse Object from the Components.

Here is a repo: https://github.com/Borntofly/MyAngularProject.git

Answer (score 1):

Theres my Repo: 
https://github.com/lohiarahul/Angular2-Silverlight-Starter

If you see, I have the Silverlight.Object() method inside my ts file.
The "Silverlight" object is in the Silverlight.js included inside the index.html file.

To use the object inside the .ts, you just have to declare a var with the same name. It should work.